# Automated web-page screenshots

Tags: windows, browser, screenshot, autoit, webpage-screenshot

We have a PC for CSS coder, with 17 different browser versions. I wonder if it is possible to write an automated screenshot script.

The algorithm :

1. Script gets the URL(s) to check.
2. Script opens browser, takes screenshot, saves it and if required, scrolls down to make other screenshot(s), until the whole page is covered.

AutoIt's API is simple and Windows oriented. Using AutoIt, how do I:

1. open a web-browser?
2. pass an URL to it?
3. make a screenshot and save it to filesystem?
4. define if scrolling is required?
5. to scroll page by monitor size (so the whole page gets covered)?

Comment: You should start with reading [documentation](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/Run.htm) - for example, Run function to run an application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At early stages of fairly complex scenarios (e.g. login -> go to a page -> click an item) you may want to look into [Selenium](http://seleniumhq.org/)! Documentation is translated to a few languages as well.

If your websites are not behind a firewall (i.e. production environment), [Browsershots](http://www.browsershots.org) could work too. There are [similar services](http://designm.ag/resources/cross-browser-testing/) (no affiliation) worth considering.

Comment: You can usually tell tools like selenium to use a hidden desktop, so this service doesn't create lots of annoying windows you can see

Comment: @daveb: hmm, interesting. We are thinking of pushing it onto remote virtual machine(s) but this unobtrusive options sounds curious at the very least. Thanks!

Comment: Can Selenium take screenshots?